# JSON.stringify() how to parse object to return only a value of a property

Tags: javascript

I have a variable, say x, that is of type [object Object]. When I run JSON.stringify(selected) it returns the properties of x like: { ["name": "Node 1", "icon": "Icon 1", "location": "xxyy" ] }. What can I use to just return the name's value, i.e. Node 1?

Comment: is property access what you are asking about? `x.name` ?

Comment: `JSON.stringify(selected[0].name)` is what you want?

Answer (score 0):

To stringify just the property of the object you can do:

```
JSON.stringify(x.name)
```